# Grails 3.2.9, Spring Security in application.yml

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to move the following (partial) Spring Security configuration from `application.groovy` to `application.yml`:

application.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.testapp.admin.Requestmap'
```

application.yml

```
springsecurity:
  securityConfigType: Requestmap
  requestMap:
    className: com.testapp.admin.Requestmap
```

The problem is that the asset resolution fails with those 2 lines in the `application.yml`. I run this in `auth.gsp`:

```
<g:each in="${Requestmap?.list()}">
    <p>permission: ${it.configAttribute}, url: ${it.url}</p>
</g:each>
```

It gives me all the `Requestmap` rows. So the `Requestmap` is available, but the asset resolution for graphics, etc. fails. If I leave those 2 lines in `application.groovy`, asset resolution works. What gives?

Comment: have you specified `grails: plugin:` in front of `springsecurity:` in your .yml?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to specify the proper hierarchy of your yml-elements:

```
grails: 
  plugin: 
   springsecurity:
     securityConfigType: Requestmap
     requestMap:
       className: com.testapp.admin.Requestmap
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I hadn't included grails: plugin: The fact that is only affected 2 lines was a red herring.